# Using CSS to toggle navigation bar instead of using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigationbar

I am developing a navigation sidebar that toggles right-and-back from the left side of the window, on a click or some similar event. Using jQuery, it seems fairly simple:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $nav = $("nav");
  $nav.hide();

  // Toggles the nav bar when clicking the nav-intersect icon.
  $("#nav-intersect").click(() => {
    $nav.animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 350);
  })
});
```

However, there is a minor issue. When I refresh the page, for a brief moment, you can see the nav bar visible, then quickly disappear, which seems to indicate that the webpage loads the nav bar element, then loads the jQuery script, which calls `$nav.hide()` to manually hide the nav bar *after* the nav bar is already visible.

As such, I want to change my nav bar to be toggled with CSS classes. I've seen websites use code such as `class="nav-open"` and toggle the presence of the class itself to show the nav bar, but I am having trouble trying to implement it with the sliding animation that my current code implements. I know it has something to do with `visibility="hidden"` and `"visible"`, so if someone could give pointers, it would be greatly appreciated!

https://jsfiddle.net/TrueshotBarrage/7kqL318b/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to move too far from what you have already you can just change what the jQuery is doing. And as Badrush suggested above, use CSS `transition` to do the animation.

Hide the `nav` with CSS and toggle the class names to hide and show. Consider giving the element a class name and select the element with that instead of the tag name. Below I named it `.sidebar-nav`.

`.sidebar-nav-trigger` could live outside or inside the `nav`. If its inside, you'll want to style/hide/show '.sidebar-nav-items' instead of the parent element.

HTML

```
<a class="sidebar-nav-trigger">Menu</a>

<nav class="sidebar-nav hide">
    <a class="sidebar-nav-trigger">Menu</a>
    <div class="sidebar-nav-items">
        <!-- nav items -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.sidebar-nav {}

.sidebar-nav.hide {
    display: none;
}

.sidebar-nav.show {
    display: block;
}

.sidebar-nav-trigger {}
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $sidebarNav = $('.sidebar-nav');

  // Toggle the nav bar when clicking the nav-intersect icon.
  $('.sidebar-nav__trigger').click(() => {
    $sidebarNav.toggleClass('show').toggleClass('hide');
  });
});
```

---

There is a lot of fancy things you could do with CSS transition. For demonstration purposes, below are styles to make it transparent and move it 50% of its width. Modify as needed.

CSS

```
.sidebar-nav {
    transition: opacity 0.4s, transform 0.4s;
}

.sidebar-nav.hide {
    pointer-events: none; /* "hides" it from mouse, a more modern technique than visibility: hidden; */
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

.sidebar-nav.show {
    pointer-events: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Is there a "preferred" way of doing something like this, since there seem to be multiple ways to do what I need to do in general when dealing with HTML/CSS/JS?

Comment: There a multiple ways to do almost anything with front-end dev. Largely depends on your project needs. It's been my opinion for many years to do as much as I can with markup and css. The technique I outline above only uses JavaScript to trigger interaction and behavior by setting classes, leaving the styling to the css.

Answer (score 0):

Why not stick with your jQuery code simply address the load issue? You can have it hidden by default and tell jQuery to show it so that it'll be hidden when the page loads.

If you want to use CSS then you can assign a `closed` and `open` classes (name them whatever) and change for each class name you have your set of css properties (width) etc. you can use `transition` css property to animate it.

Then to get it to go from one to the other you'll still need to add or remove the class from the element using JS which is easy to do.

1. Use JS to select the element
2. Use `classList` to add/remove classes as needed

https://alligator.io/js/classlist/

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you want to remove the nav bar flash. So CSS is one option, HTML another, and JavaScript yet another.

jQuery toggles visibility based on display (none or block), so use `display:none;` in your CSS like so:

```
nav {
  display:none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
}
```

If that is not fast enough, you could write it in the HTML (`<nav style="display:none;">`) but CSS should be fine.

Then, remove the hide in your jQuery because you have already hidden it:

```
$nav = $("nav");
  //$nav.hide();
```